# Gnuplot plot area background

Tags: background, plot, gnuplot, area

How to set the background only in the plot area?

I wahnt my chart look like this http://pchart.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php?ID=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set object 1 rectangle from graph 0, graph 0 to graph 1, graph 1 behind fc rgbcolor 'red' fs noborder
```